# Is it possible to use "number_to_currency" inside a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I a, building a dropdown menu in a form that displays a list of available options and their prices in this form: "service - price". My problem, however, is that it doesn't look like I can use number_to_currency inside my controller. Is there another way to achieve the same effect, or to access number_to_currency from my controller? Here is my initial effort:

```
@levels = []
DistributorLevel.all.each do |d|
  price = (d.price > 0) ? number_to_currency(d.price) : "Free"
  @levels << ["#{d.name} - #{price}", d.id]
end
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you could do with:

```
view_context.number_to_currency(d.price)
```

or

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(d.price)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```